# Leer un JSON alojado en una URL de protocolo FTP

Tags: android-studio, json, app, ftp

Quiero realizar una *App* con *Android Studio* que consulte un *JSON* alojado en un *FTP*.

¿Cómo sería dicha conexión?

Comment: Tendrías que poner un ejemplo más concreto de lo que quieres hacer, el código que tienes hecho, o explicar el algoritmo de lo que tienes pensado.

Comment: Tengo un Json (contiene dni y fechas) alojado en un FTP, la idea es desde la app ingresar el dni y poder traerme la fecha. Quería saber como poder conectar mi App al FTP para poder realizar consultas a los archivos que estén alojados en el. Las cosas que hice en Android fueron consultando a un Web Service y no se si el FTP trabaja de distinta forma. Espero haber aclarado un poco. Muchas gracias

Comment: Pero deberías poner la información editando la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Desde una App externa :
Probablemente se haya preguntado si había una forma de transferir archivos entre su servidor y su dispositivo móvil en la carretera, donde no hay una computadora disponible. Bueno, esto definitivamente resolverá eso. Aprenderá cómo transferir archivos entre un servidor FTP y su dispositivo Android con una aplicación gratuita llamada: AndFTP.</strike>

Nivel de dificultad: Fácil

1. Descargue e instale la aplicación desde Android Market.
2. Abre la aplicación.
3. La primera vez que inicie la aplicación, le pedirá que escriba la información del servidor al que le gustaría conectarse. Escriba su dirección de servidor, nombre de usuario, contraseña y puerto (generalmente 21).
4. Toca el botón de conexión.

Ahora intentará una conexión al servidor. Si la conexión es exitosa, ahora verá los archivos en su servidor, así como los archivos en su dispositivo móvil.

5. Para transferir archivos, simplemente toque el archivo, toque "transferir" y moverá la carpeta seleccionada remotamente.

[tutorial en ingles](https://blog.arvixe.com/how-to-connect-to-a-ftp-server-with-an-android-device/)

si gustas hacerlo desde el codigo:

Descargue los archivos .jar necesarios.
Primero necesitas seguir el archivo JAR:

1. commons-net-3.3.jar

Descargue aquí:

[descarga](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-start-ftp-android)

Descarga el último archivo jar y agrégalo a la carpeta libs de tu proyecto de Android.

Paso 2 Clase MyFTPClientFunctions
Crea nuevas clases MyFTPClientFunctions en tu proyecto. Ahora agregue algunas funciones de FTP en la clase recién creada.

```
FTPClient público mFTPClient = null; // Agrega la parte superior de la clase
```

Ahora agrega un método para conectar el servidor FTP. (Método para conectarse al servidor FTP)

```
public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username, String password, int port) {
    try {
        mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
        // connecting to the host
        mFTPClient.connect(host, port);
        // now check the reply code, if positive mean connection success
        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
            // login using username & password
            boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);
           /*
               * Set File Transfer Mode
               * To avoid corruption issue you must specified a correct
               * transfer mode, such as ASCII_FILE_TYPE, BINARY_FILE_TYPE,
               * EBCDIC_FILE_TYPE .etc. Here, I use BINARY_FILE_TYPE for
               * transferring text, image, and compressed files.
            */
            mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            return status;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Ahora agrega un método para desconectar el servidor FTP. (Método para desconectarse del servidor FTP)

```
public boolean ftpDisconnect() {
    try {
        mFTPClient.logout();
        mFTPClient.disconnect();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error occurred while disconnecting from ftp server.");
    }
return false;
}
```

Ahora agregue el método para cargar archivos en el servidor FTP.

```
public boolean ftpUpload(String srcFilePath, String desFileName, String desDirectory, Context context) {
    boolean status = false;
    try {
        FileInputStream srcFileStream = new FileInputStream(srcFilePath);
        // change working directory to the destination directory
        // if (ftpChangeDirectory(desDirectory)) {
            status = mFTPClient.storeFile(desFileName, srcFileStream);
        // }
        srcFileStream.close();
        return status;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "upload failed: " + e);
    }
return status;
}
```

conexión a su aplicación en Android Studio a un servidor FTP?

[tutorial desde codigo][3]

[How to start FTP in Android](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-start-ftp-android)

Comment: Aca no queremos descargas apps, aca trabajamos con codigo, Tu publicacion esta muy cercana a ser spam.

Comment: solamente era una opcion que conozco

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [answer] :P